# Error using linq-to-entities to generate xml

Tags: ajax, linq, linq-to-entities, linq-to-xml

How Come the following gives me an error along the lines of "Only parameterless constructors and initializers are allowed in Linq To Entities". I am trying to generate HTML from my entities to update an HTML table using AJAX.

```
public class Foo
{
    public int Bar1 { get; set; }
    public string Bar2 { get; set; }
    public DateTime Bar3 { get; set; }
}

XElement[] elements = (
            from x in FooEntities.Foos
            select new XElement("tr",
                new XElement("td", HttpUtility.HtmlEncode(x.Bar1)),
                new XElement("td", HttpUtility.HtmlEncode(x.Bar2)),
                new XElement("td", HttpUtility.HtmlEncode(x.Bar3)))
            )
            .ToArray<XElement>(); // Error

XElement html = new XElement("table", headerXElement, elements);
```

Comment: As a side note, you don't need to specify type argument in `ToArray` call, as it will be inferred by compiler.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, the error message speaks for itself.

> Only parameterless constructors and initializers are allowed in Linq To Entities.

LINQ to Entities can be hard to please, what do you think?
Call `ToArray` right after you get the entities so you're only dealing with LINQ to Objects:

```
var foos = (from x in FooEntities.Foos
            select x).ToArray();

XElement[] elements = (
            from x in foos
            select new XElement("tr",
                new XElement("td", HttpUtility.HtmlEncode(x.Bar1)),
                new XElement("td", HttpUtility.HtmlEncode(x.Bar2)),
                new XElement("td", HttpUtility.HtmlEncode(x.Bar3)))
            )
        .ToArray();

XElement html = new XElement("table", headerXElement, elements);
```

It's also a good practice to separate the database call (first query) and business object / XML generation (the second query) because you immediately see **what executes against the database and what goes in memory**.

Comment: I concur, haha. I figured it out just about when you posted this. i did foreach (var x in foos) html.Add(new XElement...